# intel x86 assembly code compile on windows platform

Tags: assembly, x86

I have written the following sample code for x86 processor. it is working fine with O2 compiler option in visual studio but withoutO2 option it is not working, please let me know if there is any issue here.

Sample code for your reference.

```
.386                           
.model flat,c                  
_text       segment
align       4  
public      hs_L_mls_1

L_mls_1 proc

   push    ebp
   mov     ebp, esp
   push    ebx
   push    esi
   push    edi

   mov     eax,  dword ptr[ebp+8]  ; load Lv from stack
   movsx   edx,  word  ptr[ebp+12] ; load v from stack
   imul    edx
   shrd    eax,  edx, 15
   xor     edx,  edx
   pop     edi
   pop     esi
   pop     ebx
   mov     esp, ebp
   pop     ebp
   ret                           

L_mls_1 endp

_text    ends
end
```

Thanks 
Ajith

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  What is it supposed to do?

Comment: sometimes its return value is getting corrupted.

Comment: My problem is if I include this function with my workspace,it produces incorrect results. However, I don't see why the two compiler option of code should have any effect on each other, since the registers utilized are cleared.

Comment: Check out this link to see if this could be an issue: [/O2 option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f8h5cxt.aspx)  Any chance that this is a calling convention issue where input parameters are being passed in ecx and edx instead of being pushed onto the stack? However, this is the /Gr option, not /O2 option. Try writing a similar function in C / C++ and have Visual Studio output assembly code to see the calling / return value convention.